# How to find a particular cropped image into the original image?

Tags: matlab, crop

I am performing the following steps:

- I insert a mark in an original image `img1` to obtain a watermarked image `img2`.
- I crop the the watermarked image to obtain `img3`.
- I want to crop a particular part of the original image `img1` to obtain the same part like `img3`.

My question is how to find where the cropped part is located in the orignal image?

Comment: This sounds a bit too trivial. Does `img2` have the same dimensions as `img1`? Do you have the code for extracting `img3`?

Comment: Why dont you just use the same row and column indices for cropping the img1 that you used to crop img2? e.g. im3 = img2(cropIndices); img1a = img1(cropIndices);

Comment: This is the same question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360297/matlab-how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-in-another-martrix/12084000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cross-correlation http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html

Here is an example http://www.mathworks.ch/products/demos/image/cross_correlation/imreg.html

If the cropped image has been resized I think your problem is more similar to this one http://thydzik.com/matlab-scaled-image-normalized-cross-correlation/